# How to fix a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I was trying to fix the problem in my code for the "invalid position of blit" but once I solved that another error appeared. **TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**. I tried putting int() around(when I mean around it I mean the code I tried was: `int(self.x) += int(self.changeX)`)

Here is the code, I have put it in order, meaning this is all the related content in order from the code with everything else.

(Minimalistic Example. There's actually a lot more.):

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, enemyImg, enemyX, enemyY, enemyX_change, enemyY_change):
        self.image = enemyImg
        self.x = enemyX
        self.y = enemyY
        self.changeX = enemyX_change
        self.changeY = enemyY_change

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.changeX
        self.y += self.changeY

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

#Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
enemies = []
number_of_enemies = 5
#Making a list for all 5 enemies image, x value, y value, x value change, y value change. All variables are a seperate list

for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python/CodingBee/Pygame Application Prototype/zombie.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(0.45)
    enemyY_change.append(40)
    enemy = Enemy(enemyImg, enemyX, enemyY, 0.45, 0)
    enemies.append(enemy)

#def states an event. The event will not occur unless you call the event in the main game loop.
back_ground = Background()

#Main Game Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

SCEEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SCEEN_UPDATE,150)`
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
               Player.player_jump()

        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.move()

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if Health_State == "ready":
                    Health_Fire_Sound = mixer.Sound('laser.wav')
                    Health_Fire_Sound.play()
                    Health.fire_Health(HealthX , HealthY)
                    HealthY  = playery + 10

        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
               playery += playery_change

        
screen.fill(0,0,255)
back_ground.update()
back_ground.render()

#Health Kit Movement
if HealthX >= 800:
    HealthX = 20
    Health_State = "ready"

if Health_State == "fire":
    Health.fire_Health(HealthX , HealthY)
    HealthX -= HealthX_Change


#Enemy Movement and collision check
for i in range(number_of_enemies):

    if enemyX[i] > 20:
        for j in range(number_of_enemies):
            enemyY = 2000
        Other.game_over()
        break

    Enemy.move()
    collision = Other.isCollision(enemyX[i],enemyY[i],HealthX,HealthY)
    if collision:
        BulletY = 480
        Bullet_State = "ready"
        enemyX[i] = random.randint(800,900)
        enemyY[i] = 405
        HealthX = 20
        Health_State = "ready"
        Score_Value += 1
```

Comment: `enemyX` and  `enemyY` are lists. This is not what I've xuggested in the answer to your previous question [pygame "invalid position for blit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532347/pygame-invalid-position-for-blit)

Comment: Please post the full error traceback! And BTW your example is far from being minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enemyImg`, `enemyX` and enemyY are lists. However, the arguments to the `Enemy` constructor have to be a single image and the x and y coordinate of the enemy.
You do not need the lists `enemyImg`, `enemyX`, `enemyY`, `enemyX_change` and  `enemyY_change`. Delete the lists:

```py
enemies = []
number_of_enemies = 5

enemyImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python/CodingBee/Pygame Application Prototype/zombie.png')
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    x = random.randint(0, 736)
    y = random.randint(50, 150)
    enemy = Enemy(enemyImg, x, y, 0.45, 0)
    enemies.append(enemy)
```

Note that you can get the coordinates of an enemy with `enemies[i].x` and `enemies[i].y` instead of `enemyX[i]` and `enemyY[i]`

---

Furthermore you have to move and draw the enemies in the application loop not in the vent loop.

Your code should look something like this:

```py
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, enemyImg, enemyX, enemyY, enemyX_change, enemyY_change):
        self.image = enemyImg
        self.x = enemyX
        self.y = enemyY
        self.changeX = enemyX_change
        self.changeY = enemyY_change
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.changeX
        self.y += self.changeY
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

enemies = []
number_of_enemies = 5
enemyImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python/CodingBee/Pygame Application Prototype/zombie.png')
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    x = random.randint(0, 736)
    y = random.randint(50, 150)
    enemy = Enemy(enemyImg, x, y, 0.45, 0)
    enemies.append(enemy)

#def states an event. The event will not occur unless you call the event in the main game loop.
back_ground = Background()

#Main Game Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

SCEEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SCEEN_UPDATE,150)`
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
               Player.player_jump()
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if Health_State == "ready":
                    Health_Fire_Sound = mixer.Sound('laser.wav')
                    Health_Fire_Sound.play()
                    Health.fire_Health(HealthX , HealthY)
                    HealthY  = playery + 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
               playery += playery_change

    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.x > 20:
            for j in range(number_of_enemies):
                enemyY = 2000
            Other.game_over()
            break

        enemy.move()

        collision = Other.isCollision(enemy.x,enemy.y,HealthX,HealthY)
        if collision:
            BulletY = 480
            Bullet_State = "ready"
            enemy.x = random.randint(800,900)
            enemy.y = 405
            HealthX = 20
            Health_State = "ready"
            Score_Value += 1

    #Health Kit Movement
    if HealthX >= 800:
        HealthX = 20
        Health_State = "ready"

    if Health_State == "fire":
        Health.fire_Health(HealthX , HealthY)
        HealthX -= HealthX_Change
        
    screen.fill(0,0,255)
    back_ground.update()
    back_ground.render()

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks So Much! The code worked! (I know I should avoid comments such as +1 or "thanks" but I'm very grateful for your help, @Rabbid76)